# Why are these strong parameters returning a "param not found" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, fetch, nested-attributes, strong-parameters

I have two models, a profile model and a job model.  A profile has_many jobs and a job belongs_to a profile.  I am using the cacoon gem in order to create nested forms.  In my application, someone creates a profile, and then they can add jobs.  So, by the time they are making their first job, a profile is already created, a job is not, and the form data will go to the update action (since a profile already exists, even though no jobs do).  The problem is, since there are no jobs yet, I am receiving the error:

```
param not found: profile
```

Here are the params I tried using:

```
def profile_params
      params.require(:profile).permit(:title, :category, :description, :state, :zip_code, :rate, jobs_attributes: [:firm, :position, :category, :description, :begin, :end, :_destroy])
end
```

I then switched to the following code as recommended from another stack overflow post:

```
def profile_params
      params.fetch(:profile, {}).permit(:title, :category, :description, :state, :zip_code, :rate, jobs_attributes: [:firm, :position, :category, :description, :begin, :end, :_destroy])
end
```

With the second profile_params (the one with fetch), the page will load with a successful flash message, but the job is not actually being created.  I don't think the fetch is working.  Any ideas on how to get this working?  Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure params[:profile] does exist?  Just to verify, log it (`Rails.logger.debug(params)`) and check your `development.log` file.

Comment: It exists because Im not having any problem making a profile.  Its when it gets to the update action and no jobs exist.  How do I log?  I tried typing Rails.logger.debug(params) into the console but I don't think thats how I'm supposed to do it?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: you can put it right `profile_params` function, and whenever that function gets hit, it will print it out to your `development.log` file (or rather w.e environment you are running in).  In your terminal window you can type `tail -f log/development.log` to open your log file and monitor it.

Comment: when i add the line Rails.logger.debug(params) to the end of the profile_params method, I get the following notice 'undefined method `stringify_keys' for true:TrueClass'.  When I run ' tail -f log/development.log', I get: 'NoMethodError (undefined method `stringify_keys' for true:TrueClass):
  app/controllers/profiles_controller.rb:37:in `update' '

Comment: Add it before.  When you make it the last line in the function, it is considered the return statement, and thats going to mess with your `update()` call.

Comment: The development.log file just printed a bunch of 'started get' statements.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40391/discussion-between-michael-lynch-and-philip7899)